# Incrementing Number of logins

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm not quite sure why with my query its not incrementing the number of logins by one its not even attaching it onto the query string.

```
public function update_logins($user_id)
{
    $this->db->set('number_of_logins', 'number_of_logins'+1);
    $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);   
    $this->db->update('users_logins');
    echo $this->db->last_query();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `$this->db->set('number_of_logins', 'number_of_logins + 1');` ?

Comment: That set the number of logins back to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Althought i don't know how codeigniter will work with the suggestion in comments, what i can tell you is:

Your +1 to the 'number_of_logins' will not yield the expected behavior because a string + a number usually gives an unexpected result depending on the content of the string.

Number parsing in PHP works by scanning the string for digits and number symbols. Anything it finds will be taken into account as a possible part of a number until it finds an invalid character.

In the context of a string with "number_of_logins" it will yield a value of 0 because there is nothing in that string that allows a number interpretation. But, a "10_number_of_logins" would generate a 10 and thus add a 1 would make 11.

**UPDATE**

For example:

```
(int)"3 pigs" = 3 //The first character is valid "3" but the space is not
(int)"Three pigs" = 0 //The first character "T" is invalid, thus number is 0
(int)"17.1 percent" = 17.1 //Period is a valid character
(int)"17,1 percent" = 17 //Comma is not a valid character
(int)"I fly with 3 pigs" = 0; //Even if 3 is in the string, it starts with "I" which is invalid
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I understand everything but that last part.

Comment: Converting strings to numbers is done by looking at the string and taking parts all valid characters of the string that forms a number and stopping as soon as an invalid character is found. I'll put some more examples...

Comment: All I want to do is add 1 to the column value of the field so instead of 1 it'd turn into 2 for the value.

Comment: Note i'm not entirely sure about the command (17,1), it might be valid but i logically think it's not

Comment: @JeffDavidson I don't know how to do that in CodeIgnitor cause i have never used it. My post is about how numbers are formated and that is the first part of your problem, i don't have a solution to the second part of your problem

Comment: Since i don't know anything about CodeIgniter i'll just say this: Get the current value by selecting it and then update it with a +1 instead of trying to do an update on the database value

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by `number_of_logins` being set to null (null + 1 = null). If so, set the default for `number_of_logins` to 0 and not null the field; or (if you're using mysql) try:

> $this->db->set('number_of_logins', 'coalesce(number_of_logins, 0)+1');

Here's more info on [coalesce](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce).